# How to disable the logging of timestamps for repeated tasks?

Tags: org-mode

For example, if I have a repeating TODO such as

```
* TODO item 1
SCHEDULED: [date]
- State "DONE"        from "TODO"      [timestamp]
```

How do I keep the third line from displaying? It clutters up the buffer after a while, and I have to keep deleting the lines. I don't need to have a log of the date and time I completed the task. I can tell from the agenda whether it's done or overdue.

Comment: Does customizing the variable `org-log-repeat` offer any relief to the issue described?

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setting of `org-log-done` with `C-h v org-log-done RET`. It is probably set to the symbol `time`. You can set it to `nil`:

```el
(setq org-log-done nil)
```

As @lawlist mentions in a comment, `org-log-repeat` can also be the culprit here.

You can use per file settings to enable/disable these things:

```org
   #+STARTUP: nologdone
   #+STARTUP: logdone

   #+STARTUP: nologrepeat
   #+STARTUP: logrepeat
```

which makes it easy to experiment.

Another possibility to avoid the clutter is to keep the logging but put the state change items into a a drawer. If you want to do that, you can set the variable `org-log-into-drawer` to the name of a drawer (`LOGBOOK` is the conventional name):

```el
(setq org-log-into-drawer "LOGBOOK")
```